# Is the extension of a countbly-additive measure the continuum?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that
(1) the measure space $\langle S, \mathcal{A}', \mu'\rangle$ is an extension of $\langle S, \mathcal{A}, \mu\rangle$;
(2) $A\in \mathcal{A}'\setminus \mathcal{A}$; and 
(3) $\mu_*(A) < \mu^*(A)$ where $\mu_*$ and $\mu^*$ are the inner and outer measures of $\mu$, respectively.

My question is: for any $r$ such that $\mu_*(A)\leq r\leq \mu^*(A)$, is there an extension $\langle S, \mathcal{A}'',\mu''\rangle$ such that $A\in \mathcal{A}''$ and $\mu''(A) = r$?

Comment: All the measures here are assumed to be countbly-additve. If they are finitely additive, the proposition is well-known to be true.